# Plone Authentication failing for only 1 user

Tags: authentication, ldap, plone

(Apologies for being new to Plone - previous administrator has moved on.)

One of our Plone users is failing to authenticate to Plone but we cannot find any reason for it. She logs into Novell successfully and tries to access Plone pages to edit them and the LDAP authentication used by Plone returns the message "Login failed. Both login name and password are case sensitive, check that caps lock is not enabled".

We have and LDAP plugin installed and have established nothing unusual about the user. All cookies have been removed without success.

We are running:
-Plone 3.2.2
-CMF 2.1.2
-Zope (Zope 2.10.9-final, python 2.4.2, linux2)
-Python 2.4.2 (#1, Dec 2 2008, 00:09:07) [GCC 4.1.2 20070115 (SUSE Linux)]
-PIL 1.1.5

Has anyone got any hints on how to solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I forgot to mention the 'errors' section is no help - Unauthorized exception has been removed without success.

Comment: Might the user simply be locked out of Plone (but not LDAP)? If so, how do I unlock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try one or more of these options:

- are you sure that this particular user is imported from the ldap and is not local to plone? If it's local, she probably didn't activate it from the received automatic email.
- did you check if the user password is expired in your ldap? the user is active?
- does your ldap plugin imports users using some filter (es. group, attributes..)? If so, compare her ldap group/attributes with other users.
- the user needs some phosphorus? Try to reset her password in the ldap.
- did she use special characters in her password? It could be an error of password transmission between plone and the ldap because of these special chars. Plone can smoothly handle local user's password with special chars, but sometime it fails to transmit these password to the authentication source. I've experienced this error once but i don't remember much more.
- if everything else fails you could remove the cached user in the ldap plugin and re-import it. It could be a cache error.

Comment: Thanks Giacomo:

1) all users are set up in Novell eDirectory and added to a 'plone user' group in which she is a member. Her login used to work fine but changes her pw and now does not (I should have mentioned that)
2) How do I check if user pw is expired in LDAP?
3) No filter
4) I had already forced a pw change
5) I saw the cache removal option but I was reluctant to use it as I could not see how to do it just for her and there were only 5 users in the cache and she wasn't one of them.

Comment: Well if she can login into Novell edir successfully than most likely the password and the user are still active. In the ldap plugin there's a tab "Caches". Purge all caches, it will not hurt (anyway take a backup, just for precaution).

Comment: Cache flushed without success. I have narrowed the problem down further: Open browser and nav to myportal[site]/login_form = get error straight away ie without going anywhere near novell access manager etc so nothing to do with that side of things it seems. However, might Plone lockout user independent of LDAP? Some LDAP entries in her account appear odd (eg dmremotecontrolsettings) compared to other account but these appear doing an independent ldap query outside Plone. Inside Plone (/acl_users/PortalLdap/acl_users/manage_cache) all is the same.

Comment: I have just changed her password too (in Novell as LDAP has no write privileges) but again without effect.

Comment: So when you said "I had already forced a pw change" you meant in the plone control panel? But this shouldn't work because plone (usually) is in read only mode with the ldap. You have to reset her password in the ldap and then force a purge of users caches.

Comment: This is a bit mad - she has now just managed to get in but I do not know which bit you suggested got it to wark. Thanks for you help tho.

Answer (score 0):

Check in the ZMI.  Look in /acl_users/source_users/manage_users below the Plone site, and /acl_users/users/manage_users at the Zope root, and any acl_users in between.

This is what Giacomo meant by "local to plone".  If she is defined in one of those places, and that source has priority over LDAP (likely), then her LDAP credentials aren't being used.

Comment: http://myportal.[site]/acl_users/source_users/manage_users is empty.

http://myportal.[site]/acl_users/PortalLdap/acl_users/manage_users has a list of all of the LDAP users (apparently).

So you are saying that the latter are 'local to plone'? She is in that list and so could be deleted? Or have her pw edited? I tried editing her pw in the latter which did not help.

Comment: No, I definitely didn't say that.  I said that the "source_users" in your Plone site's acl_users folder were local users, and essentially any user sources in any acl_users folders above that.  The acl_users/PortalLdap/... will be the interface to your LDAP directory.  Of course, because of PAS (which makes PortalLdap possible) there can be any number of user sources that could have priority over your LDAP source).